# A same sequence for building a convergent and a divergent series.

Tags: real-analysis

I am searching for a sequence $a_n$ of real numbers, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{\sqrt n}$ diverges.

Comment: Same question as ever : what have you tried ? Have you attempted to see if there is a candidate of the form $a_n=1/n^{\alpha}$ for a certain fixed $\alpha$, even if it is deemed to fail ? (Riemann series). You must test different blades of your swissknife !!!

Comment: I have modified your title in order that it helps people for further reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing $a_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\ln n}$ (for $n\geq 2$) will do the trick. Can you prove it?

**Hint:**

- Bertrand series
- $\int^x \frac{dx}{x\ln x} = \ln\ln x$

Comment: Side comment: show that if you replace $\sqrt n$ by $n^{1/2+0.00001}$, there is no such series. (Hint: AM-GM inequality, or Cauchy-Schwarz).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, for every $\alpha>1/2$ the series converges if $\sqrt n$ is replaced by $n^\alpha$.